# Napili Template Header Top Overlap

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili

I have a custom header I want to put on my Napili community template, however, it keeps overlapping the search bar.

Before:

[image]

After : [image]

How can I "push down" the search bar and make this section dynamic to the size of the header? The header is a custom lightning component.

Comment: Just had to make the html div around the content inherit it's position with css

Answer (score -1):

As of now, When you use custom header, you need to implement search functionality.

See this idea:

> ## [Allow header to be customized in Napili Communities Template](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dx52AAC)
>
> When creating a new community via the Napili template, it's rather limited with what you can do with the header.  I can change the background image, action colors, navigation bar, and I can also implement a completely new header if I wish.  However, if I implement a new header, then I also have to implement the my profile widget, the global search widget, and the logo as well if I want.
>
> I should be able to customize the "standard" header by doing the following:
> Changing the background color of the header (I currently do this by hacking a solid color image as the background image)
> Adding custom components to the header itself or taking standard components away, like the global search bar.